# Dynamically show Bootstrap tooltip on conditional output

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, typescript

I'm attempting to show a tooltip based on conditional output of a method that will return true if the input element's value is a number between 1 and 100.

When the validation method returns `false`, it should cause the tooltip to show, however nothing happens.

```
private observeGradeSubmission() : void {
    ...
    // Input element in question
    this.currentGradeInput.keyup(() => {
        if (!Validation.validateNumberInRange(this.currentGradeInput.val(), 1, 100)) {
            this.currentGradeInput.tooltip('show');
        }
    });
    ...
}
```

HTML node as it appears on DOM inspection with the data attributes:

```
<input name="mark" placeholder="Grade" maxlength="3"
    data-toggle="tooltip"
    data-trigger="manual" 
    data-hint="Grade value must be a number from 1 to 100" 
    class="form-control input-sm input-text-right grade-input" 
    data-original-title="" title="" type="text">
```

Both the `Validation.validateNumberInRange()` method and the `this.currentGradeInput.keyup()` jQuery methods are working as expected.

Anyone have ideas on why this is not working?

Using Bootstrap 4, latest alpha. Tooltips work as expected on mouseovers.

Comment: What is `Validation` and what type is `currentGradeInput`?

Comment: It's a method from a different class. `currentGradeInput` is the input element, as noted in the comment line above it in the code.

Comment: An HTMLInputElement?

Comment: It is a JQuery object.